# How to find the folder where an e-mail is placed?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2007

When I find e-mails using search option in Outlook I am not able to discover in what folder the e-mail are placed.

How can I do that?

I am using Office 2007 on Windows 7

Comment: Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can highlight the email and press Alt + Enter. This will bring up a properties window which lists the Location of the email in the top section.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on message > Find All > Related Messages
2. 'In Folder' shows the folder name

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most robust way I found for myself is to search across all mailbox (select **All Outlook Items** in the drop-down on the right side of the search box) and then right-click on resulting message list's header and select **Arrange By -> Folder**.